# Eye Brain Mapping

Tags: neuroscience, brain, eyes

If our eyes are separated by some kind of full proof barrier/isolation, is it possible that our brain can picture/visualize two different pictures at a time?
How the brain will function in this situation?
which are the books to read to understand in depth brain behavior?

I tried to isolate my eyes with hands/paper but i am not able to do it.

Comment: I heard about yogi learning to move their eyes independently, this may be a starting point for research.

Comment: dd3 answered this already, but here's an idea how to separate your eyes: take a pair of (sun)glasses and put a different sticker on the left and the right piece. Then put them on.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I should note that binocular vision is important for depth perception.

The phenomenon in which you are interested is called binocular rivalry (distinct images are presented to each eye).  You typically switch between the images, and sometimes, both at once (superimposed; this is called binocular transparency) or an averaged picture (binocular fusion).

You can find some good links at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_rivalry).  The [Scholarpedia page](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Binocular_rivalry) is even better.  If you don't find what you're looking for, I think searching for papers on "binocular rivalry" will give you the best result.